# How to get skinny jeans on more easily

Tags: clothing

I like to wear slim fitting jeans and trousers simply because I have fabulous legs. Sometimes I struggle to get these bad boys on - especially when they've recently been washed and have shrunk a little bit.

**How can I ease the passage of my leg through the trousers / jeans?**

Comment: The real question should be, 'How to take them off more easily?' Lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Submit your skinny jeans to a steamer session right before you put them on. The steamer will hydrate the pants, making them softer and the heat will dilate it, giving to you a little more space to pass your legs through them. Also, shave your legs, like the professionals swimmers do, to reduce the friction.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using talcum powder on your legs - this may make it easier to get on as it stops the moisture on your legs trying to stick to the inside of the trouser leg - like socks after you've been swimming.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

- Laying on your back and then after they are pulled on halfway picking your butt up and pulling them on this way. This way you get more leverage.
- Wear socks. When putting on TED hose wearing socks first sometimes makes it easier. Pick thin socks and not fluffy ones. This may make your legs feel more comfortable, as the jeans will glide over the socks. If you wear panty hose this also makes it easier.

---

You could also try adding another zipper on the waistband so that you have more room to scoot into them with. This takes sewing skills.

Answer (score 0):

I complained to my wife about jeans not being comfortable after being washed, as they were too tight and not moving with me.  She stopped using the dryer and all is fine.  Wash with cold water and let it air dry, and they will remain the right size and be only slightly stiff after washing.

Comment: I have the opposite experience. I always use the tumble dryer and never have shrinkage, my jeans washed by a friend and airdried and had shrunk.

Comment: Might be different issues.  I use “boot cut” to go over my Lucchesse’s — the tightness affects the wasteband and the “saddle” area.

Answer (score 0):

Try wearing pantyhose with control.  Your skinny jeans will slide right on and off with no problem.